# status, killproc commands in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, init.d

I am trying to migrate an `init.d` script from centos 6.6 server to ubuntu 14.04. Centos machine `start, status, stop` commands are,

```
daemon --pidfile=/path/to/pidfile /path/to/daemon/script
status -p /path/to/pidfile /path/to/daemon/script
killproc -p /path/to/pidfile /path/to/daemon/script
```

`start` command works good in its original form on ubuntu 14.04 but the other two functions, `status, killproc` are not defined on ubuntu distros.

What is the equivalent of these commands in ubuntu machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system, `killproc` is provided by `/lib/lsb/init-functions`.

http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html

Have you tried putting

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

near the top of your init script?

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/lsb/init-functions
lsb-base: /lib/lsb/init-functions

$ dpkg -S /sbin/status
upstart: /sbin/status

$ apt-cache show lsb-base
Package: lsb-base
Priority: required
```

Comment: hi Mikkel, this solves the `killproc` issue. But `status` on debian is a binary and the Centos cmd - `status -p /path/to/pidfile /path/to/daemon/script` doesn't work with debian's `/sbin/status/`. `man status` took me to `initctl` but it is not very clear, how i can pass the `pidfile` argument and get the job status. thanks man.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know how to do that portably.  But normally on Debian and Ubuntu you can use [start-stop-daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html)

Comment: It sounds like `start_daemon` is equivalent to `daemon` and `pidofproc` is equivalent to `status`, but I don't have a system to test on.

Answer (score 2):

> . /lib/lsb/init-functions

This addition of line worked for me. Thanks:)

```
stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down noip2."
    . /lib/lsb/init-functions
    killproc -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2
```