# Debian start-stop-daemon equivalent in CentOS

Tags: centos, daemon, start-stop-daemon, system-v

I have a bash script that is written in a debian-based distribution (System-V) and I want to run it under CentOS 7. There is a part of the script that runs a command as a daemon like this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE \
 --chdir "$DIR" --startas $PROGRAM --name foo --chuid "$USER" -- $ARGS
```

And stops the daemon like this:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PID \
                  --user "$USER" --name foo --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5
```

My question is how do something equivalent in CentOS 7? Is the `daemon` function in `/etc/init.d/functions` an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `daemon()` shell function from `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` on RHEL/CentOS 6 is not an exact equivalent of Debian's `start-stop-daemon`.  The fact that all of these van Smoorenburg `rc` tool libraries have subtly different helper command sets is one of the well-known problems with van Smoorenburg `rc`.

You're using CentOS 7.  You have systemd.  Write a systemd service unit.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202731/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247543/5132
- [status, killproc commands in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207669/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The known problems with System 5 `rc`*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/system-5-rc-problems.html).  Frequently Given Answers.